FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Development\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
How to Solve this problem when I try to Debugging on the Emulator

run ''flutter clean' then 'flutter pub get'
